# How can I solve this error? "command not found: puppeth"

Tags: blockchain, go-ethereum, geth, decentralized-applications

```
[eunsungahn@eunsungui-MacBookPro Blockchain % geth version
Geth
Version: 1.10.1-stable
Git Commit: c2d2f4ed8f232bb11663a1b01a2e578aa22f24bd
Git Commit Date: 20210308
Architecture: amd64
Go Version: go1.16
Operating System: darwin
GOPATH=
GOROOT=go
```

```
[eunsungahn@eunsungui-MacBookPro Blockchain % puppeth
zsh: command not found: puppeth
```

I think that I installed geth well, but instruction "puppeth" doesn't work. I heard that puppeth is installed simultaneously when geth is installed. How can I solve this problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: How did you install geth? did you install it with the helper tools?

Answer (score 1):

Puppeth command was removed from Geth in January 2023.

Read more info [here](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/tools/puppeth)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you select the "Development Tools" while installing Geth